# rake aborted! PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied sinatra

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I can't seem to get this to work. I try to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` after running `bundle exec rake db:create` and it gives me this error:

`rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/home/david/DBC/survey-gorilla-challenge/Rakefile:106:in block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)`

I've tried looking around, but it all seems like a solution for rails, whereas I'm using this with Sinatra and activerecord. I'm not sure if that makes any difference. I even tried changing my `pg_hba.conf`, which looks like this currently:

`IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
 IPv6 local connections:
host     all             all             ::1/128                 md5`

I'm not sure how to get this working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I changed my `pg_hba.conf` to

```
TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

"local" is for Unix domain socket connections only

host   all             all          127.0.0.1/32               trust
 IPv4 local connections:
host   all             PC           127.0.0.1/32               trust
 IPv6 local connections:
host   all             all            ::1/128                  trust
```

and then restarted postgres with `sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`. This gets the migration going.

Comment: Lol, you restarted using `nano`?

Comment: haha... restart PostgreSQL with `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`